# unexpected ',', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, drupal, syntax, syntax-error

I've encountered an error with the arguments I've passed to my function. So far I haven't found a clear solution through my research. The problem seems to lie in the way I've passed the values, or the values themselves.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
function hook_form_submit($form_id, &$form_data){
    //^ Do stuff above ^
    //Create Sponsor Admin
    //The values from the form are passed into the function
    create_sponsor_admin($form_data['values']['sponsorid'], $form_data['values']['admin_fname'], $form_data['values']['admin_lname'], $form_data['values']['admin_email']);
}
//Error occurs on line below
function create_sponsor_admin($sponsor_id, $a_fname, a_lname, $a_email){
   $user_name = $a_fname . ' ' . $a_lname;
   $email = $a_email;
   //do more stuff
}
```

PHP 5.2
Drupal 6
MySql

Comment: `a_lname` should be `$a_lname`...

Comment: Whoa, a second pair of eyes really helps. Sorry I missed that, but thanks, Felix, for helping by pointing it out.

Comment: The simple mistakes are often those that take the most time to find ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `$` here:

```
function create_sponsor_admin($sponsor_id, $a_fname, a_lname, $a_email){
                                                     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing "$" sign here  in function create_sponsor_admin at a_lname

try this

```
create_sponsor_admin$sponsor_id, $a_fname,$a_lname, $a_email){...}
```